# form fields update from subform

Tags: webforms

How do i get my main form fields update from subform fields in msaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the main form from subform code using:

```
Parent.Form!controlnameonparent
```

Or you can refer to a subform from a main form using:

```
Me!subformcontrolname.Form!controlnameonsubform
```

-Frink